# How can I make a timed CSS3 slideshow?

Tags: css, fade, css-transitions

How can I make a CSS3 slideshow, with fade transitions, which would be timed? For example, it would stay on  one picture for 5 seconds before starting the next transition.

Comment: Either JavaScript, or a delayed Animation. Pick your poison.

Comment: Took me about 1 min to google css3 cycling slideshow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out these demos:

http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2012/04/25/pure-css3-cycling-slideshow/#9

http://tympanus.net/codrops/2012/04/30/fluid-css3-slideshow-with-parallax-effect/

Hope it will be useful..

Answer (score 1):

After a quick google I found some solutions:

[DEMO:](http://www.alessioatzeni.com/CSS3-Cycle-Image-Slider/)

[And explanation](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2012/04/25/pure-css3-cycling-slideshow/)

Hope you can make it work